# Can I detect the number of children,While the Children Count will exceed four, in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Do I have to style all children, while children count above the four, a parent element?

I know I style `nth-child(4) ~ child` method but this method is used only for, the fourth child next siblings, but in this case, I have to style all children an parent element?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you're asking about the parent element, the answer is no. There is no CSS that can apply styles to a parent only if it has more than 4 children. You'd likely want to employ a javascript solution for that.

Comment: with CSS you cannot, only JS can save you

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you, but I want to avoid javascript :(

Comment: what kind of style you want to apply?

Comment: If, the children will exceed four, I want to see all the children with common width **250px**, if parent only contain Three children, I want to see all the children with common width **320px**, This case will solve by css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't ***have*** to use Javascript to accomplish this. Heydon Pickering wrote a great [article](https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) about using various pseudo selectors to style content based on count. I highly recommend reading the article.

`nth-last-child(n+4)` on its own gets you every element that is 4+ from the end. With 5 elements only the first is select, 6 elements 1 and 2 are selected, etc.

`nth-last-child(n+4) ~ li` is what makes the entire thing come together. `~` is the sibling selector. Used in this scenario anything before `~` is selected as well as anything that is a direct sibling to the previous matches and matches `li`.

### Update

Based on your comment in the original question I've added an additional CSS selector to get 3 or fewer. If you want only 3 change `-n+3` to `3`.

Unless you're proposed with a challenge, or really like thinking about `nth` children, this isn't something you'd normally pick up making Javascript seem like your only solution.

```css
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):first-child,
li:nth-last-child(-n+3):first-child ~ li {
  /* 3 or Less */
  color: blue;
}

li:nth-last-child(n+4),
li:nth-last-child(n+4) ~ li {
  /* 4 or More */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this article :) . Its awesome.

Comment: @LakshmiTS no problem. I've updated my answer to  do a bit better about both of your cases (3 or fewer, 4 or more).

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit unclear, but i guess you want to change all the children except the first four. So from child nr5 forward. To do that you use `nth-child(n+5)` where `n` is a counter (starts at 0), and `5` is an offset value.

If you want to select only the first 4, use `nth-child(-n + 4)`

See below solution for 5,6,7,etc child

```css
p:nth-child(n + 5) {
  color:red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>
  <p>
    aaaaaa
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: **I have to style the all children, while children count above the four**

Comment: `I have to style the all children, while children count above the four, an parent element?` i understood that he has to style the children that are after the forth child.

Comment: read all the question, he repeat it again that we want *all* the childs

Comment: At a first/second/third read of the question i couldn't figure out what he was looking for. Well, maybe my english is not that good. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: yeah, My Question is style all the children, when Count is above the four, its any idea to solve within css.